# Can I ask the question about "steam" client?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask the following question: is it possible to make Steam auto download games when I'm away from my computer? and stop downloading when I'm working.

Can I ask a Steam client related question here?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not... But I don't think there is solution to your question, at least not in steam options...

Comment: I'd agree with allquixotic below.  Games are off-topic here, but Steam is the software platform that distributes the games and not a game itself and therefore should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a valid question. I don't see a problem with asking it on the main site.

Comment: Because, my gaming.stackexchange.com account is onhold because of off-topic questions :-| ... and I'm extra cautious now. I think that I'll also start asking on meta.stackoverflow.com "Can I post code here which is syntactically wrong?"